# Is there any analysis of the Carlsen-Caruana World Championsip match by AlphaZero?

Tags: analysis, world-championship, alphazero

How cool would it be to have the world's most powerful computer analyzing games played in a match between the world's two strongest human players? Has it happened yet and is the analysis available?

Comment: Alphazero isn't a computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is: [AlphaZero on Carlsen-Caruana Games 1-8](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/alphazero-on-carlsen-caruana-games-1-8) and [AlphaZero on Carlsen-Caruana Games 9-12](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/alphazero-on-carlsen-caruana-games-9-12). We don't have seen the PGNs with their concrete lines so far.

I'm not sure how helpful that is. Just one minute thinking time … seems to be a bit short. Some deeper calculation might be more valuable.

Comment: One minute thinking time was also the rule for the match against Stockfish. Of course it is not really enough for Stockfish but since AlphaZero works in a completely different way using massive parallelism and look-ups it is fine for AlphaZero.

Comment: Having seen the video and analysis, even with one minute alpha finds some quite unusual yet effective plans. Quite good insight on creative plans.